# Sometimes it looks like nothing has been changed after an edit

Tags: support, edits, ios-app

Every once in a while, I come across an edit which appears to don't change anything, e.g. [this edit](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/105685/what-is-the-difference-between-dynamic-generation-and-procedural-generation):

> [image]

A tag is added and the title is changed. But there is also an edit in the body which appears to be identical to the original text. Perhaps a different type of whitespace or something?

How was this edit approved? More importantly, why was this edit made in the first place?

Comment: All users, regardless of how much rep he has, can choose to edit only the tags.

Comment: @mmking ok thank you. I am going to fix my question.

Comment: As the answer says, over 2k (1k on betas), there's no one reviewing what you edit, so trivial edits - as long as they're not in any way categorizable as vandalism - that remove a typo or what are actually good. What's wrong is, editing insubstantially when you're less than 2k, because the time of the reviewers is being wasted.

Comment: You completely rewrote the original question to ask something else entirely, and you should be asking the user who made the edit, probably in less accusatory tone, not asking the hive mind why one person chose to edit in the way they did

Comment: The edited text is not the same. Click "Markdown" to see differences. You usually need to flick between Markdown and Rendered to see exact changes. In this case, however, you can see the italics on rendered output.

Comment: @James There is no Markdown view in the iOS app currently.

Comment: @James if that were true, they would not have enabled features such as asking, answering, editing, commenting, etc. and if that were true, I wouldn't have an account anywhere but StackOverflow.

Comment: Well, maybe that's the case. In this scenario though, "non-edit" is not true, as there are all sorts of things being changed, even visible by rendered view in the app

Comment: @James an oversight on my part for sure, by not seeing the italics. No option for markdown view for my device. And I apologize for that. But to tell me my question is bad because I'm on the app instead of full website is a bad opinion, in my opinion. Unless I'm misunderstanding your comment

Comment: "*But to tell me my question is bad because I'm on the app instead of full website is a bad opinion*" I didn't really state your question was bad, I just stated perhaps the app is not ideal to be used for things other than simple functionality. That's a debate for another day. I've never used the app, so can't debate either. I don't use the app because of the limitations (either limitations in the app itself or because smaller device etc)

Comment: @James You edited/deleted your comment. Either way, I have conceded that this is a bad question and accepted my downvotes. We can continue this is chat if you would like. Otherwise I wish you a great day.

Comment: You too :) (I deleted as it was noise)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Anyone with more than 2000 reputation can edit *without needing approval* - so it wasn't approved; the user chose to edit.

There can be many reasons to edit; retagging and changing the title are legitimate reasons to edit.

The change to the body was the addition of *italics*, which you can see for yourself by looking at the *side-by-side markdown* of the edit. The italics are simply to emphasize what comparison you are asking for.

Comment: Ah Ty. No option for markdown on iOS app.

Comment: Didn't know that! But if you look carefully at your screenshot, you can see italics! :)